$\log \log (\frac{2}{||x||})$ in $W^{1,2} \setminus L^\infty$ of a ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$
Let $\Omega = B(0,1/2) \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, and let
$$
u(x) = \log \log \left(\frac{2}{||x||}\right) \quad for \quad x \in \Omega.
$$
I have to show that $u$ is in $W^{1,2}(\Omega) \setminus L^\infty(\Omega)$. It is easy to see that it is not in $L^\infty$ because the logarithm is continuous and it explodes as $2/||x||$ tends to infinity.
I´m having problems showing that $u$ is in $W^{1,2}$. I have shown that it is in L^2 but I don't know how to compute or show that $\nabla u$ is in $L^2$.
Can someone help me?
Thanks in advance!

Well, for starters it's a straightforward computation to show
$$\nabla u(x)=\frac{-x}{|x|^2\log(2/|x|)}$$
So we now need to try to bound $\Vert \nabla u \Vert_{2}$.
Firstly,
$${\Vert \nabla u \Vert_2}^2=\int\limits_{\mathbb B^2(0,1/2)} |\nabla u(x)|^2\mathrm d^2x=\int\limits_{\mathbb B^2(0,1/2)}\frac{1}{|x|^2{\log(2/|x|)}^2}\mathrm d^2x$$
Because the integrand has spherical symmetry, it makes sense to switch to polar coordinates. We thus write this integral as
$${\Vert \nabla u\Vert_2}^2=\int_{0}^{1/2}\int\limits_{\partial\mathbb B^2(0,r)}\frac{1}{|x|^2{\log(2/|x|)}^2}\mathrm d^1x~\mathrm dr \\ =\int_0^{1/2}\int\limits_{\partial\mathbb B^2(0,1/2)}\frac{1}{r^2~{\log(2/r)}^2}\mathrm d^1x~\mathrm dr \\ =\int_0^{1/2}\frac{1}{r^2 {\log(2/r)}^2}~2\pi r\mathrm dr$$
So therefore, it is pertinent to consider the integral
$$I=\int_0^{1/2}\frac{1}{r~{\log(2/r)}^2}\mathrm dr$$
Whence ${\Vert \nabla u \Vert_2}=\sqrt{2\pi I}$.
First, transform $r=t/2\implies \mathrm dr=\mathrm dt/2$ and transforms our integral to
$$I=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{t~{\log(4/t)}^2}\mathrm dt$$
We can in fact more generally consider
$$I(\lambda,p)=\int_0^1\frac{1}{t~{\log(\lambda/t)^{p+1}}}\mathrm dt$$
This integral can be dealt with neatly via substitution. Let $s=\log(\lambda/t)\implies t=\lambda \mathrm e^{-s}~\text{and}~\mathrm dt=-\lambda \mathrm e^{-s}\mathrm ds$ which transforms our integral to
$$I(\lambda,p)=\int_0^1\frac{1}{t~{\log(\lambda/t)^{p+1}}}\mathrm dt=\int_\infty^{\log(\lambda)}\frac{1}{(\lambda \mathrm e^{-s})}~\frac{1}{s^{p+1}}~\big(-\lambda\mathrm e^{-s}\big)\mathrm ds \\ =\int_{\log(\lambda)}^\infty \frac{1}{s^{p+1}}\mathrm ds=\frac{\big(\log(\lambda)\big)^{-p}}{p}$$
So in our case
$$I=I(4,1)=\frac{1}{\log(4)}$$
Thus
$$\Vert \nabla u\Vert_2=\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{\log(4)}}<\infty$$
So $$\nabla u\in L^2\big(\mathbb B^2(0,1/2)\big)$$
Now all you need to do is show $\Vert u\Vert_2$ is also finite to show that $u\in W^{1,2}(\mathbb B^2(0,1/2))$.
